# Make floated element in column layout ride up to meet element above

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have 3 `div` elements that all have `width:50%` but have undefined heights. Now say these elements all have the attribute `float:left`.

Due to the `width:50%` attribute, the three elements are now in a two column layout, the first element sits left of the second, and the third sits below both the first.

Now, if the first `div` is **50px** tall, and the second `div` is **200px** tall, the third div sits below the line created by the taller div, and thus a big white space of **150px** is created between `div 1` and `div 3`.

How can one prevent the white space from occurring?

PS, the `div`s are being generated dynamically!

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WQ6CQ/)

Comment: @avrahamcool cool, just give me two secs

Comment: Based on strictly your description, you can't, without JavaScript, due to rule #5 http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position

Comment: I think it can be done if the second element is floated right..

Comment: In general, these types of layouts require client side scripting (JavaScript).  Take a look at: http://masonry.desandro.com/ and http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Ok, I just checked it, and it works with Pure CSS, check out my answer.

Comment: @j08691 Indeed, I suspected as much, lol note the `javascript` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make the Second element float right

See that [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/fSE6F/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="First"></div>
<div class="Second"></div>
<div class="Third"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.First
{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

.Second
{    
    height: 90px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: right;
}

.Third
{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**Edit:** If you have an unknown number of div's, 
something like this **HTML** (alter the sizes as you want)

```
<div style="height: 50px;"></div>
<div style="height: 90px;"></div>
<div style="height: 70px;"></div>
<div style="height: 50px;"></div>
<div style="height: 90px;"></div>
<div style="height: 70px;"></div>
<div style="height: 50px;"></div>
<div style="height: 90px;"></div>
<div style="height: 70px;"></div>
```

Just use this **CSS**:

```
div
{
    width: 48%;
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: #09F;
}
div:nth-child(odd)
{
    float: left;
}
div:nth-child(even)
{
    float: right;
}
```

Check out this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/fSE6F/2/)

Comment: could work, although the `div` elements are being generated **dynamically**, this solution also wouldn't work for more than a two column layout. Thanks

Comment: You are wrong, it works with any number of rows you want. and with dynamic content and heights. check out my updated answer..

Comment: **columns** dude, lol not rows, in a three or more column layout, one could make every third element float right, but the problem would still persist

Comment: You answered my question though, and I'm using your code, thanks man!

Comment: oh, sorry.. I didn't read it correctly. For a N Column Layout, you would have to create N containers, each of 100/N width, and 100% height, and fill them accordingly. I'll create a Fiddle shortly. you will have to create it wisely because you want the content to be dynamic..

Comment: @proPhet http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/fSE6F/4/ the dynamic content always has the same height.. but it will work also with changing height.